# VSTS unable to load the service index for source 401

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I'm aware of the other posts about the same signature. I still can't resolve my issue after going thru them.

My team uses VSTS's build definition for continuous integration. 
[image]

This build definition works fine until the lastes pull request. 
I'm running into the error msg below during the Nuget Restore

> 2018-06-20T00:37:27.6438127Z System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CBT/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

I do have https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CBT/nuget/v3/index.json in the nuget.config, and there is **nothing changed** in the nuget.config in the failing PR

I can nuget restore and build the entire solution successfully on my local machine using VS2017. The only related change in the PR is that instead of using package.config, it uses packagereference to get the nuget package. I tried to move back to using package.config, the build would still fail with the same error msg.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the Credentials for feeds outside your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the VSTS feed with credentail (PAT or alternate credential) in the specified `nuget.config` file.

Such as:

```
nuget sources update -Name "vstsfeed" -Source https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CBT/nuget/v3/index.json -Username "Alternate username" -Password "alternate password" -configfile /path/to/nuget.config
```

Then you can commit the changes for the `nuget.config` file and push to VSTS repo. And build again to check if it works.

Comment: Why would you recommend to put a password into source control?

Comment: The password will be encoded in `nuget.config` file, so it's not put a password into source control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command as shown in the accepted answer - also, you can add the feed in a nuget.config file placed in the root of your repo

> Notice, this shows how to add credentials for a custom feed with spaces in the feed name: `My Nuget Artifacts`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="My Nuget Artifacts" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ConsotoOrg/_packaging/Consoto/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <My_x0020_NuGet_x0020_Artifacts>
      <add key="Username" value="justme" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xyzyoqyvslyfs1t1khru6wd33gebujhpr9moocbujfhv8ukxtxyz" />
    </My_x0020_NuGet_x0020_Artifacts>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <!--
        Used to specify trusted signers to allow during signature verification.
        See: nuget.exe help trusted-signers
    -->
  <trustedSigners>
    <author name="microsoft">
      <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
    </author>
    <repository name="nuget.org" serviceIndex="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json">
      <certificate fingerprint="0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
      <owners>microsoft;aspnet;nuget</owners>
    </repository>
  </trustedSigners>
</configuration>
```

> FWIW - In recent days, I've found I can clear up some NuGet restore errors by removing the `trustedSigners` section from the config

Answer (score 0):

This is not what the problem was with the OP but I'm adding a note here since I found this question while searching for the same error message.

In our case we were building a .net 5 app for in Azure DevOps. We had to upgrade to a newer version of NuGet using the NuGet tool installer. Then the restore worked just fine using the .Net Core task with the restore command.